# Fill column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy

I have 2 data frames, df1:

```
ID       Created Date          Days_Diff
L-22       2016-03-24            220
L-25       2016-02-12            200
```

df2:

```
ID       Closed Date
L-22      2017-01-03
L-25
```

The objective is to recalculate the Days_Diff because it doesn't the exact values.
so I did the following for now:

```
      df1['Days_Diff2'] = [int(i.days) for i in (df2['Closed date'] - df1['Created Date'])
```

The probleme is the following: Some ID's doesn't have a Closed Date so the calculation can't be done(I think I'll have NaT). I would like to have Days_Diff = Days_Diff2 if Days_Diff2 can be calculated, if not then Days_Diff stays the same.

Is it possible ? Any trick or twist can be done ? I need a pro here :D

Thank you

EDITED: check sample above and I would like to have: df1:

```
    ID       Created Date         Days_Diff          Days_Diff2
    L-22      2016-03-24            220         (2017-01-03 - 2016-03-24)
    L-25      2016-02-12            200                  200
```

Comment: can you display some minimal example on the two dataframes?

Comment: I did please check

Answer (score 0):

There is one possible way, although without more code it is hard to see. You can do it using a try and an except, but you need to separate the code more so that it does each ID in turn, i.e.

```
try:
  #The code that you normally want to run
except:
  #The code that you want to run if it fails - i.e. if you have a NaT, it will then do a different calculation
```

Without more code, that is about as much as I can say...